# Android starting an activity with Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE and extra return result does not return

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to do programmatic update to the application I am writing, since it is not a Google Play application and I want to provide a way to do updates.

I've been searching around and found out how to start the Android installer after I download the APK for the update, but I need to get a result from the installer, that tells me if the update succeeded or not, or if it was cancelled by the user.

I saw a bunch of questions on StackOverflow about this, and the answers usually involved using a broadcast receiver. The problem with that is that it can only receive intents about the package being installed, not about canceled installs of fails.

I did some more research and it seems the Intent API provides some extras such as Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, which if set to true should return a result from the installer activity - I guess via onActivityResult. Unfortunately this doesn't work. Is there anybody that got this working/does it work like this?

Here is the code preparing the installer activity start, that I currently have:

```
            Intent installApp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
            installApp.setData(downloadedApk);
            installApp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
            installApp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
            installApp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME, context.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
            context.startActivityForResult(installApp, 1);
```

Comment: `EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT` is new to API Level 14 -- are you testing this on an Android 4.0+ device?

Comment: I am facing the same issue currently trying to invoke in app install for a non playstore account. This seems like a very old thread but since you've reached the solution for it can you please share a proper solution that you have implemented as I have whacked my brain over the pseudocode and I'm still getting no where. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use Fragments? The onActivityResult will be called from the Activity or Fragment you have called startActivity(...). Fragment#startActivity(...) does exist. Use it to get the Fragment's onActivityResult(...) called.
If you are not using Fragments, this Workaround will work.

**Workaround Pseudocode**

```
// CURRENT_VERSION is a const with the current APK version as int

Activity#onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  checkForUpdaterResult();
  /*...*/
}

Activity#checkForUpdaterResult() {
  final int updateVersion = preferences.getInt(UPDATE_VERSION, -1);
  switch(updateVersion) {
    case -1:break;
    default: 
      // updateVersion = oldVersion is smaller than the new currentVersion
      boolean success = updateVersion < CURRENT_VERSION;
      onUpdaterPerformed(success, updateVersion , CURRENT_VERSION); 
    break;
  }
}

Activity#startUpdate(File pAPK) {
  perferences.putInt(UPDATE_VERSION, CURRENT_VERSION);
  /*...*/
}

Activity#onUpdaterPerformed(boolean pSuccess, int pFromVersion, int pToVersion) {
  Toast.show("Update success: " + pSuccess);
  /* e.g. migrate DB */
  /*...*/
}
```

Comment: Indeed it appears I was using the activity's startActivityForResult() instead of the one from the fragment I was in. I've done the necessary update and now I get a result when the update is cancelled, however when it succeeds, it closes the application. Thanks for the tip, very useful!